# Theme Integration using composer in yii2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2-advanced-app

I have tried integrating adminlte theme in my web app using composer as the package and demonstration provided on https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset. It is working fine but now I am trying to integrate Afro v1.1 - Admin Bootstrap Template. I want to integrate this theme through composer but I am not finding any possible way to do this.

Comment: You just download theme and change assets of new theme to old theme

Comment: I'm asking for integration through composer but not manually.